# Change dataframe by grouping info per user

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
user   events 
  A      X
  A      X
  A      Y
  B      Z
```

Using pandas, how can I get a final dataframe like the following?

```
user   X    Y   Z
 A     2    1   0
 B     0    1   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = df.pivot_table(index='user', columns='events',
                     aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

print(res)

events  X  Y  Z
user           
A       2  1  0
B       0  0  1
```